# Enable/disable 'Remove filters' button, depending on active remote filters for grid.store

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, store

I have an ExtJS grid with a store that is filtered and sorted remotely. These requests are handled serverside using PHP.

I also have a button in the grid's toolbar to remove the filters on the store that uses the entryGrid.filters.clearFilters() function.

I would like to enable/disable this button depending on if there are any filters active on the store. So that when de store is loaded for the first time (without any filters) the button is disabled.

So I thought about putting a listener on the store.load function.

What would be the cleanest way to check if there are any filters active, if indeed this is possible?

I searched the manual (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) for grid, store and filters, but couldn't find any reference..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already tried using listeners but i'd do it like this (in the store):

```
listeners: {
    load: function(){
        if(!this.isFiltered())
        {
            //<add actions to disable the button>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the isFiltered() works with remote filtering.

Comment: this.isFiltered() keeps returning false, even if there indeed is a filter active.